# Talking to printer from Python CGI

Tags: python, excel, printing, cgi

I have a Python CGI. I want to print the data in the page. There will be a print button and when the user clicks teh button, I need to do some processing and send the data to the printer. I similarly want to implement 'Export to excel'. Please let me know how to do these

Comment: When you Googled "Print from Web Browser" and "Web Server File Downloading" what did you learn?  This is not "Please Write Code For Me.com".  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to print to the user's printer, or the server's? If it's the user's, this is a job for client-side Javascript, not CGI.